# ¿Como comparar una consulta con 2 variables a la vez en una tabla de la BD?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tengo una aplicacion elaborada, todo funciona excelente, solo tengo un detalle: Necesito que al realizar una consulta (La placa de un vehiculo) esta se compare a la vez con 2 variables de una tabla en la BD (placa_1 y placa_2) ¿como puedo lograrlo? ya que la consulta solo se vincula con la variable (placa_1) actualmente, pero no es la idea. Espero que puedan ayudarme porfavor

```
$busqueda=""; 
$busqueda=$_POST['busca']; 
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("pnb"); 
if($busqueda != "") { 
    $busqueda = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accidentes WHERE placa_pv LIKE '%".$busqueda."%'")
}
```

Comment: Muestra el código con el que haces la consulta

Comment: El resultado de la busqueda se imprime en una hoja tipo pdf, esta es la parte del codigo en la que hago la consulta

$busqueda="";
$busqueda=$_POST['busca'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("pnb");
if($busqueda!=""){
$busqueda=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accidentes WHERE placa_pv LIKE '%".$busqueda."%'")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo tienes que agregar una condición más a tu consulta SQL

```
SELECT * 
FROM accidentes 
WHERE placa_pv LIKE % <$busqueda> % OR 
      placa_2 LIKE % <$busqueda> %
```

Comment: Mil gracias amigo, ya lo probé y me funciona